# Wrong ID given in Doctrine2 OneToOne mapping

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-one

I am seriously stack right now with the problem I have occurred with OneToOne mapping.

So let me show what I currently have:

`OrderItem` entity

```
/**
 * OrderItem
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="order_item")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class OrderItem
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    // ... //

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserPricingOption", mappedBy="orderItem")
     */
    private $userPricingOption;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Order", inversedBy="items")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $order;

    // ... //
```

`UserPricingOption` entity

```
/**
 * UserPricingOption
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_pricing_option")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class UserPricingOption
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    // ... //

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="OrderItem", inversedBy="userPricingOption")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $orderItem;

    // ... //
```

so generated tables look like this:

`order_item` table

```
 * `id` 5
```

`user_pricing_option` table

```
 * `id` 12
 * `order_item_id` 5
```

So now I am trying to do the following:

```
echo $orderItem->getId(); // gives 5, `GOOD`
echo $orderItem->getUserPricingOption()->getId(); // gives 5 `BAD` (completely different user_pricing_option row),  it should return 12.
```

I seriously have no idea why is that, please find the raw Doctrine query:
Keep in mind that query contains way more info than the showed examples above

```
SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.guid AS guid_2, t0.created_at AS created_at_3, t0.modified_at AS modified_at_4, t5.id AS id_6, t5.guid AS guid_7, t5.created_at AS created_at_8, t5.modified_at AS modified_at_9, t5.user_id AS user_id_10, t5.order_item_id AS order_item_id_11, t5.pricing_option_id AS pricing_option_id_12, t13.id AS id_14, t13.guid AS guid_15, t13.created_at AS created_at_16, t13.modified_at AS modified_at_17, t13.user_id AS user_id_18, t13.order_item_id AS order_item_id_19, t13.product_variant_id AS product_variant_id_20, t0.order_invoice_id AS order_invoice_id_21, t0.order_id AS order_id_22 FROM order_item t0 LEFT JOIN user_pricing_option t5 ON t5.order_item_id = t0.id LEFT JOIN user_product_variant t13 ON t13.order_item_id = t0.id WHERE t0.order_id = ? [131]
```

So basically `$orderItem->getUserPricingOption()->getId()` always returns the same ID as `$orderItem->getId();`

Anyone possibly see what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

OneToOne bidireccional?
Try to define in joinColumn the name with column to reference id.

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="OrderItem", inversedBy="userPricingOption")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_item_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $orderItem;
```

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional